# DAX - Month Name column error when dropped in value field

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a simple date table (marked as a Date Table)

[image]

the Date column is native to it, the rest are calculated columns.
This issue will be about these of them:

```
Month Name = FORMAT(Dates[Date], "Mmmm")

Month = Month(Dates[Date])
```

Both set to "Don't summarize".

I dropped them into value field of a visual out of curiousity, and a curious thing happened - despite "don't summarize" they took MIN form of value to display, but Month Name came out incorrect.

Image 1: 3 out of 4 lines in the column *First Month Name* are wrong, unlike *Month* which is fine.

[image]

Image 2: added Date to the row fields to check - line by line it's fine, but subtotal still wrong:

[image]

Image 3: I filtered *Month Name* in data view for February, to see which lines are for *Month* value of 1 - there is none.

[image]

This is a blank new report, no measures, no filters - that's all it is.

If someone can explain why this happens, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The columns with "Earliest"/"First"/"Min" ***are*** summarizing because they are implicit measures in a matrix visual. Since there are multiple months in one quarter it has to aggregate somehow.

The month name is a text field, so it sorts alphabetically by default. If you want it to sort by month number instead, you can use the [Sort by Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-sort-by-column#sort-using-the-sort-by-column-button) feature to sort `Month Name` by `Month`.

Comment: alphabetical sort makes total sense.  The sort by Month was already in place though, I double-checked, it's there.   I accept your answer, because my question was about Why and you answered that.  Thanks a lot!!